# Unique ID parameter in Docker-Compose

Tags: bash, docker, awk, docker-compose, zabbix

## What I'm trying to achieve

When I'm launching `docker-compose.yml` I can launch a `zabbix-agent` container with a unique ID as a parameter.

## What I've tried so far

I created the following config:

```
  zabbix:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-trunk
    ports:
      - "10050:10050"
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ZBX_HOSTNAME="$MY_ARG" 
      - ZBX_SERVER_HOST="$MY_SERVER"
```

Now I'm trying to figure whether there's a way to launch a script to populate `$MY_ARG` internally.

## A possible workaround

Simply launching `docker-compose up` inside a script where I can add arguments and read them internally as such:

```
…
# a script running before the docker-compose command:
export DIST=`grep -Po "^[A-Za-z]*" /etc/issue`
unique_id=$(case $DIST in
            Ubuntu)
               dmidecode -s baseboard-serial-number | tail -1
               ;;
            Raspbian)
               awk 'END{print $3}'  /proc/cpuinfo
               ;;
            *)
               echo None
               exit 1
        esac)

if awk -F= '/own/ && $2 != "" {err=1} END{exit err}' $ENV.env
then echo MY_ARG=$unique_id >> /etc/environment
# alternative way: export MY_ARG=$unique_id
fi
```

Any thoughts? Is this really the best way?

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208979/docker-run-script-in-host-on-docker-compose-up), but without a good answer. My suggestion would be to create your own Docker image (based on the original image), where you set the environment variable. The idea of containers is that they run independently from the host environment, so having some kind of pre/post script run on the host does not fit well into the Docker philosophy.

Comment: So using an environment variable is not so bad after all :), thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing an ID using dmidecode (or /proc/cpuinfo in RPi) as a hostname, I'll let you know how it all went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I just had to add `export unique_id` and use `$unique_id` in the docker-compose.yml file.

Another problem I ran into was running `docker-compose down` and then `docker compose up`, so in order to do so I added the variable in front of the `docker-compose` command like this:

```
unique_id=MY_ID docker-compose up
```

Works like a charm!